# Dealing with derived properties with same name as in base class using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, setter

I will try to explain my best, but it is a tricky one to explain.

I am having a problem using reflection when a derived object redefines a property already in a base class.

Let's consider the following classes to start with:

```
// The base class
namespace MyNamesapce
{
    public abstract class MyClassBase: IMyClassBase
    {
        [JsonConstructor]
        public MyClassBase()
        {

        }

        public string Info { get; set; }
        public string Unit { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

// MyClassArray is most of the time used
namespace MyNamesapce
{
    public class MyClassArray<TType> : MyClassBase, IMyClassArray<TType>
    {
        public MyClassArray()
        {
        }

        [JsonConstructor]
        public MyClassArray(IEnumerable<TType> value, TType minValue, TType maxValue)
        {
            MinValue = minValue;
            MaxValue = maxValue;
            Value = value;
        }

        public IEnumerable<TType> Value { get; set;  }
        public TType MinValue { get; set; }
        public TType MaxValue { get; set; }
    }
}

// In some rare cases we need 2D arrays
namespace MyNamesapce
{
    public class MyClass2DArray<TType> : MyClassArray<TType>, IMyClass2DArray<TType>
    {
        private int[] _arraySize { get; set; }

        public MyClass2DArray()
        {
        }

        [JsonConstructor]
        public MyClass2DArray(TType[][] value, TType minValue, TType maxValue)
        {
            MinValue = minValue;
            MaxValue = maxValue;

            _arraySize = new int[2] { value.Count(), value[0].Length };

            Value = value;
        }

        public new TType[][] Value
        {
            get
            {
                TType[][] array2D = new TType[_arraySize[0]][];

                // Reconstruct the 2D array
                TType[] tmpArray;
                int startIdx = 0;
                for (int numArrays = 0; numArrays < _arraySize[0]; numArrays++)
                {
                    tmpArray = new TType[_arraySize[1]];
                    Array.Copy(base.Value.ToArray(), startIdx, tmpArray, 0, _arraySize[1]);
                    startIdx += _arraySize[1];

                    array2D[numArrays] = tmpArray;
                }

                return array2D;
            }
            set
            {
                // Should not be able to set _value to null
                if (value == null)
                    return;

                base.Value = value.SelectMany(v => v).ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I now need to get all the properties from all instances of MyClassArray and MyClassArray2D. You will say, there are plenty of threads discussing that very point, just use "GetType().GetProperties()" for the former and use "GetType().GetProperty(..., BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)" for the latter.
The problem is that I do not know in advance which class is being processed. In my system when deserialising a Json, instances of both MyClassArray and MyClassArray2D have to be reconstructed, which is done using the following setter:

```
public static void SetProperty(this Object obj, string propName, Object value)
{
    PropertyInfo info = null;
    object[] indexer = null;

    string[] nameParts = propName.Split('.');

    if (obj == null) { return; }

    var props = obj.GetType().GetProperties();

    for (int idx = 0; idx < nameParts.Count() - 1; idx++)
    {
        try
        {
            indexer = null;

            // Try to access normal property
            info = obj.GetType().GetProperty(nameParts[idx]);

            if (info == null)
                continue;

            obj = info.GetValue(obj, indexer);
        }
        catch
        {
            info = null;
            indexer = null;
        }
    }

    if (obj != null)
    {

        // !!! Note that here, using declare only will only work when using derived classes
        PropertyInfo propertyToSet = obj.GetType().GetProperty(nameParts.Last(), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly); // | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
        propertyToSet?.SetValue(obj, value);

    }
    else
    {
        throw new SystemException($"Could not find the property {propName}");
    }

}
```

As you can see an object is passed in to SetProperty() (that can be of any type).
When it is of type MyClassArray, there are no problems, but if it is of type MyClassArray2D it does not quite work as the latter redefines "Value", which will break the logic as 2 properties called value will exist. I need a way to detect that.
The first loop seems to do the right thing. "obj = info.GetValue(obj, indexer);" will return "obj" containing all the versions of "Value". The problem is in the next part of SetProperty().
How can I detect when more than one "Value" property is in "obj"? And how to always pick the derived version of "Value"?
Also if I just use "BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly" as done here in my code snipet, properties from the base class get lost/disappear, which is undesirable.
Is there maybe a way to return in "obj" all the properties without the duplicates coming from the base class? Or some kind of property filter maybe?

Comment: Why are you using `new` instead of declaring the base methods virtual and overriding them? *That's* the real problem

Comment: Also, why are you declaring your own "array" type? There are several problems here, including the fact that `T[][]` isn't a 2D array, it's a jagged array that can contain a different number of items per row. A 2D array is `T[,]`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos They are of different type. As far as I know, overrides only work when properties have same return types? The array format is irrelevant to my question, but T[,] is not supported by WCF if you must now ;-)

Comment: That's another problem in this design, not an excuse for using `new`. If the derived class has issues with base class members, you're using the wrong base class. Inheritance means that the derived class `is-a` base class too, and can be used everywhere a base class is used

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I know very well about inheritance. This is what I had to do here and is out of topic. I know that it is very ugly, but the only other option would be to make MyClass2DArray independent of MyClassArray, which is not an option.

Comment: On the contrary, that's the very topic. This code is unreadable. The fact this code is so ugly is a clear sign you're using the wrong approach to solve whatever the *actual* requirement is. Such code is simply not needed. What are you trying to do in the first place? If the two classes are unrelated, why have one inherit from the other?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, these classes are related. All the reasons why "new" is being used in this very case cannot be explained here. I agree with what you said, but it cannot be changed. This is part of a much bigger system where the setter of "Value" in MyClassArray() contains a rather complex logic, which I'd rather not duplicated into an independent MyClassArray2D() class. Maybe I should? Either way, I am very much interested in an answer to my actual question :-)

Comment: _"This is part of a much bigger system"_ - the system is broken. You obviously need to rethink the whole design.

Comment: If you want to share logic, use a separate method, possibly a generic one, that accepts the interfaces. Inheritance isn't a great reuse mechanism. It can't be stressed enough that inheritance should only be used to mean `is a`. There's a reason eg LINQ operators are members in separate classes instead of members of a base `Collection` class. `System.Numeric.Vectors` deals with both 1D vectors and 2D matrices by using *sepatare* classes to hold the algorithms.

Comment: `I am very much interested in an answer to my actual question` the answer is to fix the broken design. I repeat, the code is unreadable. The question is unreadable because of this. You haven't even explained any actual JSON serialization problem. Why are all those attributes used? They aren't needed by either JSON.NET nor System.Text.Json. What's the point of `SetProperty`? None of the popular serializers needs such a method. All of them would work just fine with the public properties. If you wanted to customize a type's serialization you'd create a custom serializer

Comment: When you deserialize a JSON string you specify the target type, so you *do* know what types are involved. You wouldn't need all this code. Unless your DTOs have interface or base class properties instead of the concrete ones, which means the deserializer would have to guess what type to use. Something that can be done in advance, which is why JSON.NET emits extra metadata. That alone is a warning sign - the DTOs should reflect the actual data.

Comment: In any case, I think you can replace the entire `SetProperty` method and any similar reflection code by using [FastMember](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member). Instead of creating property accessors over and over, FastMember caches the accessors, allowing you to use `var accessor = TypeAccessor.Create(type); accessor[obj, propName] = rowValue; `

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I wish I could just share my screen with you :-) It is not as simple as you may think. Attributes are for WCF. I will remove them. There is no problem on Json deserialisation side. You right, I do know the types at this stage. SetProperty() is used to populate dumb down classes that are to be sent through a WCF channel.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I appreciate your pointers. I will check FastMember.

Comment: @progLearner I've used WCF since it came out. I even had to write some non-standard channel code, when I had to call "SOAP services" that used non-standard headers (ebXML). WCF isn't used for JSON. It's simply not built for that. Yes, I know about WCF Rest, it was a failure and became obsolete as soon as MVC came out 12+ years ago. WCF's DataContractJsonSerializer can't even handle dates

Comment: Instead of trying to jury-rig a 12 year old technology to do something it was never meant to do, you should *seriously* consider replacing it with a modern technology. It's quite likely that *90% of your current code* can be replaced by just a couple of lines in a .NET 6 minimal API. How much of your current code is just trying to make WCF work with HTTP and JSON? How much is trying to emulate lifecycles and lifetimes that make little sense in an HTTP service?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, well, as far as I know I am stuck with WCF in C#. Json is used in my system to reconstruct a class structure on one side of the system (once when initialising the system). WCF is used for user interaction as it completely disconnected from the Json.

Comment: WCF is used to create SOAP services, not user interaction. That's the only use case that actually worked. In all other cases, there were better alternatives. For example the NetTCP binding was essentially an attempt to recreate .NET Remoting. Why not create an HTTP endpoint instead? Or use gRPC, which is a *lot* faster?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, do you have any specific pointers on .NET 6 that you think I should look into?

Comment: It depends on what your actual use case is. If you have multiple clients that want to call an HTTP service on a server, a [minimal Web API project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) is a good starting point. JSON is used for serialization by default. Notice how small the code is in .NET 6 - a single Program.cs with 20-30 lines. For two-way communicatin you can use a [SignalR project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Another popular choice is creating a [gRPC service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/?view=aspnetcore-6.0). The binary data format is highly efficient, it's possible to send data from the server to the client, and the DTO and operation schema is defined in advance, and can even be used to generate client code. Versioning is a lot easier too. It's the closest thing to binary WCF bindings, except it's a lot simpler, faster and cross-platform

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I will check that out, thanks. My use case is a bit unconventional though, in the sense that the service is used for multiple applications to interact via independent sessions with the same piece of hardware, while all installed on the same computer. Nothing is exposed to the outside world.